# validate() Mock Constraint Testing in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, constraints

I have a unit test that I am trying to get the validation to succeed on.

Basically, when I call `badMockedSecureFile.validate()`, it is not doing what I expect, and that is failing validation for the two fields, `encryptedFileName` and `encryptedFileData`.

When I break in the debugger, I simply get a `null` value for `badMockedSecureFile.errors` in the subsequent assert.  Here are my two files:

Any input would be greatly appreciated.  I couldn't find an exact similar question.  I'm using **grails 2.2.4** with **Oracle JDK 1.7.0_25** if that matters any.

**EDIT**: I just wanted to note that I removed the `mockForConstraintTests` call and it seems to be working now. I get this feeling I didn't RTFM somewhere and this behaviour changed in unit testing, or is something else going on?

**SecureFile.groovy**

```
class SecureFile implements Serializable {

    /**
     * An unencrypted version of the file name.  This file name is unencrypted
     * when the appropriate password and key combo is used and it is never
     * persisted to the database for security (see transients below).
     */
    String fileName

    /**
     * Unencrypted version of the file data.  Never persisted to the
     * database for security (see transients below).
     */
    byte[] fileData

    String encryptedFileName
    byte[] encryptedFileData
    Date dateAdded
    Date dateUpdated
    Date dateDeleted

    static constraints = {
        encryptedFileName(nullable: false, blank: false)
        encryptedFileData(nullable: false)
    }

    static transients = ["fileName", "fileData"]

    static belongsTo = [user: User]
}
```

**SecureFileTests.groovy**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.mixin.support.*

import org.junit.*

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(SecureFile)
class SecureFileTests {

    static final String SAMPLE_PDF_FILE = "fileEncryptionTestSample.pdf"

    void testConstraints() {
        def samplePdfFile = new FileInputStream(SAMPLE_PDF_FILE)

        // Not really encrypted for this mock.
        def mockedSecureFile = new SecureFile(
                encryptedFileName: "--Not-Really-Encrypted--",
                encryptedFileData: samplePdfFile.getBytes()
                )
        mockForConstraintsTests(SecureFile, [mockedSecureFile])

        // Validation should fail if both properties are null.
        def badMockedSecureFile = new SecureFile()

        assert !badMockedSecureFile.validate()
        assert "nullable" == badMockedSecureFile.errors["encryptedFileName"].code
        assert "nullable" == badMockedSecureFile.errors["encryptedFileData"].code
    }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to chime in and note that I removed the `mockForConstraintTests` call and it seems to be working now.  I get this feeling I didn't RTFM somewhere and this behaviour changed in unit testing, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

Remove code from badMockedSecureFile.errors["encryptedFileName"].code  .

You will get as you expected.

```
mockForConstraintsTests(SecureFile)

// Validation should fail if both properties are null.
def badMockedSecureFile = new SecureFile()

assert !badMockedSecureFile.validate()
assert "nullable" == badMockedSecureFile.errors["encryptedFileName"]
assert "nullable" == badMockedSecureFile.errors["encryptedFileData"]
```

Comment: Wait, what? Why would I instantiate a `MyTest` class instead of `SecureFile`? Also I added a follow up that I removed the `mockForConstraintsTests` function call and it works now. So I guess my question really should be edited.

Comment: Sorry Thomas. MyTest class used by me to check myself. I didn't change to SecureFile here. Now see. Try this now.It will work. I think mockForConstraints have to put for valitate the constraints.

Comment: No dice.  I have to remove the `mockForConstraintsTest` line.  Is this being done automatically as of Grails 2.2.4?  It works perfectly fine in the UnitTest for the domain class if I just do not call `mockForConstraintsTest()`.  Unfortunately, the documentation does not show it this way.